# Sidebar Icons not showing OSX 10.11.6

Tags: macos, finder

I have previously deleted the plist to get back the icons in the finder sidebar from applications such as Chrome and Pages.

That worked for awhile but now they have disappeared again.

Any idea how to fix this problem permanently?

Answer (score 1):

When you have an open dialog in any application and are missing your sidebar, press the Sidebar icon to toggle the sidebar visibility.

[image: Sidebar icon]